# Sending SMS to real test device (not emulator) via DDMS or emulator instance

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms

**What is working:-**
I'm developing my Android applications with Eclipse.  I can start two emulator instances and quite happily send SMS messages between them and do whatever I need to.  I prefer to do my testing with a real device though so I have my Android device connected and working away happily and I can run and test my applications.

**What is Not working:-**
My problem is sending an SMS to the real device through the DDMS or an emulator instance.. I can't find a way to achieve this. When I have the real device selected in the DDMS the emulator control is inactive.  I've been hunting around for the last hour trying various searches and I've come up empty handed so if someone can help by letting me know if it is is possible to spoof an SMS to a real test device that would be great. If it is possible can you point me in the right direction of some reading material?

**My current workaround:-**
I can bite the bullet and just test on two emulators or I can borrow a phone from "She who must be obeyed" and send real messages but too long without a phone makes her grumpy and I try to live by the "Happy wife, happy life" philosophy..

Thanks for reading and I hope someone can help!

Paul

Comment: I do not think that this is possible with real devices. However, I wish you a good luck in your findings!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some more time looking around I've come to the same conclusion as Yury, I don't think this can be done using the DDMS or an emulator instance.

However I have found this little nugget on the marketplace which seems to serve my needs well enough: [SMS Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.n39x.sms_test)

It just sends a broadcast intent with the origin address and message body you set. Just thought I should post it here in case it helps anyone else.

**UPDATE:**

This emulator works only for devices below android 4.2

Comment: Does this app need root? I tried running it on my unrooted HTC One X and nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Thanks. I also found *SMS-Test* and *SMS Generator* on Google Play. :)

Comment: Link "SMS Emulator": We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.